# interactive scatter plot with python

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, plot

Hi I need to create an interactive scatter plot in python. With interactive I mean that the user can draw rectangular area of interests over the scatter plot. These ROI are enclosing some region of the points and are meant to gate out outliers from the center of the distribution. Is it possible to do something like this in python? Matplotlib does not seem a viable option because of the complex interactions required here, maybe it is possible with Qt. Does anybody has a hint how to start?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940387/interactive-mode-in-matplolib

Answer (score 0):

I believe pyQt and matplotlib are the right choice.

Have a look at this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/07/a-live-data-monitor-with-python-pyqt-and-pyserial/

You could use spinboxes to define your rectangle interactively as I am not sure if this was possible by using the mouse pointer on the plot window.